# undefined reference to ros::init with beginner_tutorials

Tags: catkin, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to compile `move_base` (so, the navigation stack, really) from scratch, so I can modify it. However, I get

```
undefined reference to `ros::init(int&, char**, std::string const&, unsigned int)'
```

and more. To investigate this, I tried to compile the vanilla beginner tutorial with `talker.cpp` and `listener.cpp`. See code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tsbertalan/da2914f5c6a5ce2ab2a8ca9436460e80), in particular [`catkin_make.out`](https://gist.github.com/tsbertalan/da2914f5c6a5ce2ab2a8ca9436460e80#file-catkin_make-out).

I'm using GCC 4.9:

```
tsbertalan@Sigurd:~/catkin_ws$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: [snip]
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.4 (Ubuntu 4.9.4-2ubuntu1~16.04) 
tsbertalan@Sigurd:~/catkin_ws$ c++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: [snip]
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.4 (Ubuntu 4.9.4-2ubuntu1~16.04) 
tsbertalan@Sigurd:~/catkin_ws$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: [snip]
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.4 (Ubuntu 4.9.4-2ubuntu1~16.04) 
tsbertalan@Sigurd:~/catkin_ws$
```

I've tried the `catkin_make clean; catkin_make` combo with both the 4.9.4 and 5.4.1 alternatives, with the same results.

and I don't think any of my [environment variables](https://gist.github.com/tsbertalan/da2914f5c6a5ce2ab2a8ca9436460e80#file-env-out) specially enable C++11 features.

Anyone have pointers on what might be going wrong, or how to debug this? I have ROS Kinetic, on Ubuntu 16.04.

As a new clue, `catkin_make VERBOSE=1 2>&1 | grep so` gives, among other things,

```
/usr/bin/c++   -std=c++0x    CMakeFiles/talker.dir/src/talker.cpp.o  -o /home/tsbertalan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/talker -rdynamic /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libroscpp.so -lboost_signals -lboost_filesystem /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librosconsole.so /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.so /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librosconsole_backend_interface.so -llog4cxx -lboost_regex /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libxmlrpcpp.so /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libroscpp_serialization.so /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librostime.so /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libcpp_common.so -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_chrono -lboost_date_time -lboost_atomic -lpthread -lconsole_bridge -Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/kinetic/lib
```

When I then look for symbols in libroscpp.so using `objdump -TC /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libroscpp.so | grep ros::init`, I find

```
0000000000124a40 g    DF .text  00000000000007da  Base        ros::init(int&, char**, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)
```

to be the closest to what's used in talker.cpp

```
talker.cpp:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `ros::init(int&, char**, std::string const&, unsigned int)'
```

Is the fix then to self-compile *roscpp* without c++11? This seems like it shouldn't be needed. ros-kinetic-full was initially installed via apt-get as per the online instructions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253557/undefined-reference-to-ros::init-with-beginner_tutorials/) by [tsbertalan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28618/tsbertalan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2017-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rohbotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/23169/rohbotics/) on 2017-02-04**:
Do you have a custom GCC install? Ubuntu 16.04 should have GCC 5.4.0 by default

**Comment by [tsbertalan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28618/tsbertalan/) on 2017-02-04**:
@rohbotics 4.8, 4.9, and 5 are all installed by apt. See [gccVersionCheck.out](https://goo.gl/xoQZ6X) in the gist. This machine was updated from I think an original 14.04 install, so maybe the old GCC version was kept for my user.

**Comment by [tsbertalan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28618/tsbertalan/) on 2017-02-04**:
@rohbotics Moreover, using `sudo update-alternatives --config gcc` to set the version to 5.4.1 doesn't fix the error.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-02-11**:
I think gcc on 16.04 defaults to C++11 , and it's used to build all of the ROS packages, so the solution is probably to remove any c++0x flags if you're specifying them as part of your build.

**Comment by [tsbertalan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28618/tsbertalan/) on 2017-02-11**:
I have no such flags. Just now, I created a new `~/newcatkin_ws` and put [this](https://gist.github.com/tsbertalan/85580e3c0105084cdcca4a1156fe14e2) plain-vanilla tutorial in it, but it still fails in the same way. Pretty crazy.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-12**:
@tsbertalan: can you try *forcing* C++11 support for `beginners_tutorials`? Just add `add_definitions(-std=c++11)` to its `CMakeLists.txt`. With these flags the 'newest one wins', so that should allow us to see whether the `-std=c++0x` is the problem here.

**Comment by [tsbertalan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28618/tsbertalan/) on 2017-02-12**:
@gvdhoorn I added that at the top, but results were the same. Should I have added it elsewhere in the file? I know the order matters.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-12**:
Run the build with `VERBOSE=1` and post the compiler command line.

**Comment by [tsbertalan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28618/tsbertalan/) on 2017-02-12**:
Ok, I added the output to [catkin_make _j1 VERBOSE_1](https://gist.github.com/tsbertalan/85580e3c0105084cdcca4a1156fe14e2#file-catkin_make-_j1-verbose_1) in the gist. Output doesn't change.

**Comment by [sdyy](https://answers.ros.org/users/43908/sdyy/) on 2019-07-10**:
Also meet this issue when gcc = 4.9, change to gcc5 and rm -rf build will be OK, But driveworks need gcc<=4.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, after doing all these labyrinthine diagnostics, I tried both `gcc -v` *and* `g++ -v` and found them to be different versions. I tried for a while to use update-alternatives to get them both pointing to 4.9, but that didn't change my errors. I then just did `sudo aptitude reinstall gcc; sudo aptitude reinstall g++` and it seems to be compiling fine now (and both report v5.4.1). Sheesh, don't know how I managed to mess that up.

---

Originally posted by [tsbertalan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28618/tsbertalan/) with karma: 63 on 2017-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ginger](https://answers.ros.org/users/54690/ginger/) on 2020-05-09**:
Thank u so much for your help. I solved the error just as what u did, but my gcc/g++ version did not change after `aptitude reinstall`, but it really works.